# Joomla CMS, Hika Shop Ecommerce and retail POS

Tags: e-commerce

My client would like a CMS platform such as Joomla plus an e-commerce site like Hikahop plus they re also looking to integrate their ecommerce with their retail store POS. What would you recommend and how can we do this? Is Shopify the only option?  The client is looking at Vend as a POS solution?

Answer (score 4):

Shopify is definitely a leading choice for this type of integration. If the client prefers HikaShop, however, integration with POS systems can certainly be done. We have a client with a fabric store that synchronizes thousands of products daily between the brick and mortar POS and the HikaShop online store. But you are looking at significant custom development up front to make that happen.

Answer (score 2):

Given you want integrated POS, Shopify is the only sensible option.